# Splitting one irregular column into many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I need to split one irregular column into many subsidiary columns using various delimiters SQL Server.

I have a column called Event_Name that has the following irregular data:

```py
EVENT_NAME
----------------
ABBRV
Noun Noun2 Noun3 - Adjective - MM/DD/YYYY - LOCATION
Noun Noun2 - MM/DD/YYYY (#1) - LOCATION 
Noun Noun2 - MM/DD/YYYY - Adjective (#1) - LOCATION
Noun, Noun1a Noun2 Noun3 - Adjective: MM/DD/YYYY - Adjective2 - LOCATION

like:
"QRCC"
"Pool Party Dance - Late Night - 12/12/2020 - North"
"Lawn Bowling - 12/12/2020 (#1) - South "
"Lawn, Pool Class Signups - Early: 12/12/2020 - Canceled - North" 
"Pool Event - 11/31/2020 - To Be Announced (#1) - South"
```

I previous tried to solve this using Python but, now, the way the pipeline in structured, I really need to do the split in the SQL query and use the embedded date as a condition.

In Python, I was working on something like

```py
new= df['Event_Name'].str.split(" ",n=2, expand = True)
new[3] = new[2].str.split("-", expand= True)[1]
new[4] = new[2].str.split("-", expand= True)[2]
new[5] = new[2].str.split("-", expand= True)[3]

new[3] = new[3].str.split(' ()', expand=True)[2]

new[5]=new[2].str[-4:]
data = new[[0,1,3,5]]

0    |  1    | 3          |  5
-------------------------------
Noun | Noun2 | xx/xx/xxxx |  LOCATION
```

but that doesn't account for the Adjectives and doesn't capture that in the rare occasions that there's a `"Noun, Noun1a Noun2 Noun3 - Adjective: MM/DD/YYYY - Adjective - LOCATION"`  format, the output should be

```py
0            |  1   | 3          |  5
----------------------------------------------
Noun, Noun1a | Noun2|  xx/xx/xxxx|  LOCATION
```

so the actual desired output would be

```py
(Noun and Noun1a if not null) or ABBRV | Noun2 or null | Noun3 or null | DATE | Adjective or null| Adjective 2 or null| LOCATION  

OR

Event Cat | Detail | Detail | DATE       | Status     | Status  | LOCATION
-------------------------------------------------------------
QRCC
Pool      | Party   | Dance  | 12/12/2020 | Late Night |         | North
Lawn      | Bowling |        | 12/12/2020 |            |         | South 
Lawn, Pool| Class   | Signups| 12/12/2020 | Early      |Canceled |North 
Pool      |Event    |        |11/31/2020  | To Be Announced |    | South
```

The occasional `"(#1)"` is irrelevant and can be ommited. How can I do this as part of a SQL call?

Comment: can you  show some sample data and desired output.. it's not clear what the expected delimiters can be etc.. just for clarification

Comment: updated to include some example data

Comment: from your sample..is it safe to assume that "-" is the column delimiter? is it always a fixed number of columns to be derived from the text?

Comment: what version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: `11/31/2020` is not a valid date. SQL is not designed to shred unstructured text data like this. Try to keep the parsing task in Python or some other environment that's good at string handling.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server >=2016 just use STRING_SPLIT

Comment: The data I'm using in PHI health data so this is just nonsense I typed up that matches the format since I cannot share the original data. There isn't always a "-" between the columns and there isn't every possible column of data in every row, that's the main issue. I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio 13.0.16000.28 I cannot do this in Python as the pipeline we have to use doesn't have a supported Python server.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest: This design is awfull. Any chance to change the input is better than dealing with this. That means: Use my suggestion to parse this only if you cannot change the way you get the data. But sometimes we have to deal with crap...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('QRCC')
,('Pool Party Dance - Late Night - 12/12/2020 - North')
,('Lawn Bowling - 12/12/2020 (#1) - South')
,('Lawn, Pool Class Signups - Early: 12/12/2020 - Canceled - North') 
,('Pool Event - 11/31/2020 - To Be Announced (#1) - South');
```

--The query

```
SELECT TheFirstFragment.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Event Cat]
      ,TheFirstFragment.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Detail]
      ,TheFirstFragment.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Detail]
      ,AssumablySomeDate.value('/x[contains(.,"/")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS HopefullyTheDate
      ,AssumablySomeDate.value('/x[not(contains(.,"/"))][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Status1]
      ,CASE WHEN TheThirdFragment NOT IN('North','South') AND TheThirdFragment NOT LIKE '%/%' THEN TheThirdFragment END AS [Status2]
      ,CASE WHEN YourStringAsXml.value('count(/x)','int')>2 THEN YourStringAsXml.value('/x[last()]','nvarchar(max)') END AS [LOCATION]
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT t.YourString AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' - ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(YourStringAsXml)
OUTER APPLY(SELECT Cast('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(YourStringAsXml.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)'),', ',',') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) B(TheFirstFragment)
OUTER APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT YourStringAsXml.value('/x[contains(.,"/")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) C(AssumablySomeDate) 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT YourStringAsXml.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)')) AS D(TheThirdFragment);
```

The idea in short

The `APPLY`s will pre-compute some columns

- We use XML to split this in fragments at the *blank-dash-blank*
- We take the first fragment as repeat the splitting at the single blank (but we have to deal with the *comma blank* first)
- We search the fragments for the one. which contains a slash and split this at the single blank too.
- We pick the third fragment *as is*

The column list

- picks the 1st, 2nd and 3rd part of the first fragment
- The part which contains the slash might be a date (but look closely at 11/31/2020!)
- The part which does not contain the slash might be the additional info like "Early"
- The third fragment might be the status, if it is neither North, nor South, nor contains a slash.
- And - if there are more than 2 fragments, the last one should be the location.

The usage of *might* and *should* show clearly, that this can break at any time...